# Solving for $n$ in this equation

Tags: functions, products

I have this next equation:

$c=\left( p^n\cdot c_0\right)\cdot \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}f(j)$

where:

1. $c, p, c_0$ are known constants.
2. $n$ is to be determined from this equation.

The function $f(j)$ is given by: $f(j)=\dfrac{1}{n-1}j+1$, where j is a natural number inside the range $\left[0, n-1\right]$

Plugging $f(j)$ into the main equation gives:

$c=\left( p^n\cdot c_0\right)\cdot \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left( \dfrac{1}{n-1}j+1\right)$

Is there any easy way to solve for $n$? Or do I need a computer?

Comment: I think you mean $f(j)$ in your multiplication

Comment: edited with a new explanation of my problem.

Comment: Had the factors been of the form $ax+b=a(x+b/a)$, you could have expressed the product in terms of the Gamma function ($a^{r+1}\Gamma(r+b/a-1)/\Gamma(b/a-2)$). I never heard of a generalization of Gamma with square roots... You can still pull $a^{r+1}$ out of the product.

Comment: Yves Daoust, let's put it this way. I need to solve for "n" in the equation above. Do you think it is possible without having to use a computer algorithm? Does "n" have an algebraic solution?

Comment: Is $x$ an unknown ??? @karmalu already made a remark about this.

Comment: I think I'll need to open another question better clarifying what I am trying to achieve. No, $x$ is not an unknown. I use $x$ to range from $0$ to $n-1$ inside the product.

Comment: No, you used $j$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28811/discussion-between-jose-lopez-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: I'd prefer that you fix your formulas for others to see them.

Comment: Yves, I've reworded the entire question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You say that $c_n$ is a known constant. Do you mean that it does not depend on $n$ ?

Comment: No it does not. $c_n$ is a number, you can call it $Q$ if it helps.

Comment: Denoting $c_n$ is a misleading choice; it means that $c$ varies with $n$ !

Comment: Wow, I think that was the confusing part. I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $x=j$ in the product, the solutions of the equation

$$c_n=\left( p^n\cdot c_0\right)\cdot \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(a\sqrt j+b)$$

must be found by exhaustive comparisons

$$c_0=c_0b=:t_0\\
c_1=pc_0b(a+b)=p(a+b)t_0=:t_1\\
c_2=p^2c_0b(a+b)(a\sqrt2+b)=p(a\sqrt2+b)t_1=:t_2\\
c_3=p^3c_0b(a+b)(a\sqrt2+b)(a\sqrt3+b)=p(a\sqrt3+b)t_2=:t_3\\
\cdots$$

There is apparently no limit of $n$ (hence the search is infinite), and equality may very well never arise or arise several times.

**Update**:

Due to a late changes in the problem statement, $a=\frac1{\sqrt{n-1}},b=1$, and the recurrence relations do not hold.

With these definitions, the products can be computed once for all as a function of $n$ alone, but that doesn't change the conclusion regarding the resolution.

Comment: I am sorry I confused you Yves. I was just confusing $x$ with $j$. An even later change in the problem states $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ and $b=1$. Do you think you can edit your answer to fit my updated question? So, are you saying there is no way to find $n$ here?

Comment: I said the exact opposite: I gave the explicit procedure to find all solutions. But I suspect that your problem statement is invalid, that the equations are just an inductive definition of $c_n$, and the RHS are missing.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time and patience. As I said I have some basic maths knowledge and can't easily get to understand how I can solve for $n$ given your answer. I think you suggested making all products by hand? If only you could take a deeper look at my question and reword your already worked-out answer. Thanks

Comment: Whether you do it by hand or computer is irrelevant, you have to compute all products. But this problem statement looks improbable.

Comment: The thing is that I need to know how many terms I'll need to compute whether by hand or computer. $n$ is not known until I've solved the equation, but I cannot solve the equation without actually knowing what's the value of $n$.

Comment: What you say is nonsense. If you need to solve the equation for $n$, you obviously don't know $n$ in advance.

Comment: What I tried to say is this: in order to compute those products ($t1$, $t2$, ...) in your answer, I need to know how many terms there will be. Should I stop at $t_{10}$ or at $t_{30}$?

Comment: If I believe your problem statement, you must never stop, even after finding a solution, as there can be others. Actually, your problem is exactly as if you said: $z_n=1$, find $n$.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I forgot to say I am looking for the first (smallest) ever found. How does this change the resolution?

Comment: Work by increasing $n$ and stop when you find a solution (if ever).

Comment: Let's study the particular case $f(j)=2$. In this case the solution is unique and well-defined. How can this change for $f(j)=\sqrt{j}$ given a well-defined domain?

Comment: What is "the" solution in the case $f(x)=2$ ???

Comment: $n=\dfrac{\log{(c_n/c_0)}}{\log{(2p)}}$. Remember, $c_n$ is just a number and does not depend on $n$.

Comment: I just saw your answer to my other remark. With $c_n$ a constant, let $c$, you can compare the values of $c/c_0p^n$ to those of $\Pi_n$ (computed once for all) and stop when they cross. It could be possible to predict an $n_{\max}$ by providing an bound on $\Pi_n$.

Comment: But I said $c_n$ was a constant in my original question! My fault anyway. Can you please reword your main asnwer please? And further explain how can I "compare" those values you said.

Comment: Compare means tell if greater than or smaller than.

Comment: I understand. But still don't get to know how to get an algebraic solution for solving $n$ (if it exists at all). Please, reword your answer now that everything is clear.

Comment: You won't find an algebraic answer. Like I said in the beginning, without the square root you would have the Gamma function and would need to take its inverse; there is no known equivalent function for the square root.

Comment: I see... so no algebraic solutions. What if I had something like $f(j)=e^j$ or $f(j)=cosh(j)$? It won't make things easier I think. Can you please explain in your main answer how can I use the Gamma function so to get an algebraic solution IF f(j) were $f(j)=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot j+1$?

Comment: Again, thanks for your time. I've further reworded my original question. Can you provide a detailed answer now as your main answer?

Comment: $e^j$ makes it easy to solve; $\cosh(j)$ not. About Gamma, I was wrong, it doesn't suffice to invert Gamma; the equation is of the ugly form $p^n(\Gamma(n+\alpha)+\beta)=\gamma$, to be solved numerically.

Comment: Let's proceed then with $ae^{b(n)j}$. How can I do it?

Comment: Solve $c=p^nc_0ae^{b(n)n(n-1)/2}$. (Take the logarithm.)

Comment: I think you meant $c=p^nc_0a^{n-1}e^{b(n)n(n-1)/2}$ right? Again, as a math newbie, may I ask how did you get the exponent? Why $b(n)n(n-1)/2$? Thanks!

Comment: Sum of $j$ from $0$ to $n-1$ (after taking the log).

Comment: It was long but definitely worth it. I admire how patient you were with me. Big thank you.

Comment: ;-) ;-) ;-) ;-) ;-)